# Как передать в register_callback_query_handler сам callback и название функции которая должна запускаться при передачи n-ого callback

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram, бот

Как передать в register_callback_query_handler сам callback и название функции которая должна запускаться при передачи n-ого callback?

```
def register_callback_handler(dp: Dispatcher):
    dp.register_callback_query_handler(callback="SignUp_Student", run_task="Student_SignUp")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def callback_handler(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery, callback_data: dict, run_task: str):
    # Обработка callback_query
    # ...
    asyncio.create_task(run_task())

def register_callback_handler(dp: Dispatcher):
    dp.register_callback_query_handler(
        callback_handler,
        lambda callback_query: callback_query.data == "SignUp_Student",
        run_task=Student_SignUp
    )
```

`callback_handler` - это функция обратного вызова, которая будет вызываться при нажатии на определенный callback, а Student_SignUp - это функция, которая должна быть запущена.

В функции `callback_handler` вы можете обработать параметры `callback_query` и `callback_data`, и затем запустить функцию `run_task` в асинхронном режиме, используя `asyncio.create_task(run_task())`

Comment: смотрите у меня есть получается метод async def SignUp_Student(callback: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext): pass именно он и должен запуститься после получения callback = SignUp_Student

Comment: получается при регестрации должна быть такая запись def register_callback_handler(dp: Dispatcher):
    dp.register_callback_query_handler(
        SignUp_Student,
        lambda callback_query: callback_query.data == "SignUp_Student",
        run_task=Student_SignUp
    )

Comment: Да, вы правильно понимаете. `def register_callback_handler(dp: Dispatcher):
    dp.register_callback_query_handler(SignUp_Student, lambda callback_query: callback_query.data == "SignUp_Student", run_task=Student_SignUp)`

Comment: звучит глупо но я в вопросе перепутал местами названия, callback = Student_SignUp, а вызываемая функция SignUp_Student, вашего ответа я написал вот этот код def register_callback_handler(dp: Dispatcher):
    dp.register_callback_query_handler(Student_SignUp,
        lambda callback_query: callback_query.data == "Student_SignUp",
                                       run_task=SignUp_Student)

Comment: первый параметр он выделяет, и выдает ошибку при запуске NameError: name 'Student_SignUp' is not defined